# three.js - create cube around tube geometry

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, webgl, three.js

Please find the URL for tube geometry: [3d tube with 200 points of data passed in JSON format.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12530637/three-js-move-camera-inside-tube-geometry)

As number of points vary for the length of the tube, how do I create a transparent cube around tube geometry dynamically to cover entire tube structure inside the cube and the whole scene look like a pipe inside a surface ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

geometry.computeboundingbox() which adjusts the scale at which the box is and postion of where the box should be placed

```
scaleX = (max.x -min.x);
scaleY = (max.y -min.y);
scaleZ = (max.z -min.z);

positionX = min.x + scaleX/2;
positionY = min.y + scaleY/2;
positionZ = min.z + scaleZ/2;
```

Comment: `tube.computeBoundingBox();
var centerX = 0.5 * ( tube.boundingBox.max.x - tube.boundingBox.min.x );
var centerY = 0.5 * ( tube.boundingBox.max.y - tube.boundingBox.min.y );
var centerZ = 0.5 * ( tube.boundingBox.max.z - tube.boundingBox.min.z );
camera.target.position.addSelf( new THREE.Vector3( centerX, centerY, centerZ ) );` - @Gero3 this gives me error "cannot read property position of undefined at last line.